# Apache Log4j2 class-specific logging in a package using log4j2.xml

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I'm using log4j2 and I have a package containing lots of classes which follow a specific name-schema. I want all messages from all classes of a specific type in a corresponding log-file.

The easiest way would be if Logger would support wildcards like this: `<Logger name="de.gmxhome.golkonda.features.*Type1" ...>`, but I learned, that log4j2 doesn't support that.

I know, I can either name the loggers in class-files (e. g. all `*Type1`-classes as `public static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger("Type1");`), or configure a separate logger for each class. But I do not want to change the code and since I'm dealing with many classes, the `log4j2.xml` would get very big. I was trying different filters, but could not get the right one.

Is there a way to configure log4j2 to do that?

Example: I have two classes

```
package de.gmxhome.golkonda.features;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Logger1 {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Logger1.class);

    public static void log() {
        LOGGER.info("logger1");
    }
}
```

Let's say, I have the same class named `public class Logger2` in the same package. The log-message should go in two appender:

```
    <Configuration status="WARN">
    <Loggers>

        <Properties>
            <Property name="pattern">%d{DEFAULT} %-5level [%t] %c -
                %m%n%xException{full}</Property>
        </Properties>

        <Appenders>
            <Console name="appenderLogger1" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                <PatternLayout pattern="1: ${pattern}" />
            </Console>
            <Console name="appenderLogger2" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                <PatternLayout pattern="2: ${pattern}" />
            </Console>
        </Appenders>

            <Logger name="de.gmxhome.golkonda.features" level="info" additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="appenderLogger1" />
                <AppenderRef ref="appenderLogger2" />
            </Logger>

    </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

Is there a filter that can be applied on the appender for that purpose or is there another way to achieve this goal.

Comment: Cheers for the crystal clear question, although Java is not my language. Could you please add some filters you tried. It would make sense not to repeat work that doesn't work ;-) Enjoy SO.

Comment: I expected the [RegexFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html#RegexFilter) to do that, but it only filters the message, not the other data like class-names.

Comment: Can you please clarify - do you want the logs from each class within the package "de.gmxhome.golkonda.features" to go to its own *appender*, or do you want to use the same appender (e.g. file appender) and just send logs to a separate log file for each class?

Comment: I actually want all messages of classes of a specific type (let's say `de.gmxhome.golkonda.features.*Type1` e. g. `de.gmxhome.golkonda.features.Class1Type1` and `de.gmxhome.golkonda.features.Class2Type1` in one file, and `de.gmxhome.golkonda.features.*Type2` in a different file without configuring a specific Logger for each class or naming the Loggers.